# Directive Testing with injected host component

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have a directive, in which I am getting the component instance via inject keyword like this:

```
export class MyDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private component: MyBaseComponent = inject(MyBaseComponent);
  ...
}
```

MyBaseComponent is an abstract component, from which multiple other controls are derived (e.g. MyTextComponent).
Example usage of MyDirective inside html-template of a component:

```
<my-text-component my-directive>
```

So the 'component' property inside 'MyDirective' class is becoming the 'my-text-component'.

The problem is though the unit-testing with jest. 
The empty skeleton code for unit-testing looks like that:

```
describe("MyDirectiveTest", () => {
  let directive: MyDirective;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyDirective, MyBaseComponent, MyTextComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: MyBaseComponent, useClass: MyTextComponent }],
    });
    directive = new MyDirective();
  });

  it("should initialize correctly", () => {
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am getting the following error:

**NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`.**

And it's showing exactly the code line with the inject() as source of the error.

PS: 
Before you suggest adding @injectable() decorator to MyDirective, 
I already tried that, besides Directives and Components are injectable per default anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a component/ use an existing component to test a directive, a directive cannot be initialized separately, that is why you are getting this error. Instead use `TestBed.createComponent(MyTextComponent)` to initialize the component and test the directive through the component.

[Angular docs for directive testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing-attribute-directives)

NOTE: Since you initialize the directive as a class, it does not have any Angular context. It's just a class, that is why inject is giving you an error.

```
directive = new MyDirective(); // <- line with the problem!
```